# cx_Oracle: unhandled data type 250

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have code:

```
    def get_same_value(self):
        cursor = self.con.cursor()
        try:
            obj_type = self.con.gettype('MY_PKG.MY_TYPE')
            obj = obj_type.newobject()
            cursor.callproc('MY_PKG.getSameValue', [obj])
            return obj.aslist()
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

On string return obj.aslist() I get error:

```
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Object_ConvertToPython(): unhandled data type 250
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of my_pkg.my_type? What version of Oracle Client and Database are you using? What version of cx_Oracle? What version of Python?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Python - 3.5, cx_Oracle - 5.3. On another PC it work. On server does not work(((

Comment: You can try cx_Oracle 6 as well -- but if it works in one place and not another, my suggestion is that the problem is your version of the Oracle Client libraries and database. What are those?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga cx_Oracle backward compatible?

Comment: Yes, with the exceptions listed in the release notes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not cx_oracle master but i'm thing getattr doesn't work with pl sql level object.

You can access oracle object only if it's created on sql level.
`CREATE TYPE test_type AS OBJECT ( 
      id number, .... ) ;`

Comment: Omject created in DB

Comment: PL/SQL records and collections are in fact supported as well, but this may be an example that doesn't work currently. I'll need the PL/SQL definition of the type that is failing.

Comment: cx_oracle is using oracle oci to access db. And in oracle 11< oci has no support for PL/SQL package types.In oracle 12 support for these type was added. [oci 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090945.html). The quote from documentation _Support for PL/SQL package types and Boolean types for PL/SQL parameters_

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz how i can check oci version?

Comment: first question which version of oracle are you using 11 , 12 ?